# How to display line chart with keys associated with more than one set of values? angularjs-nvd3-directives

Tags: nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I´m using [angularjs-nvd3-directives](http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/line.chart.html) for display a chart line, but I need to display datasets that have more than one set of values for the same key. For example:

```
"key": "estimation"
"values": actual: [[x1,a1],[x2,a2]...]
          deviation: [[x1,d1],[x2,d2]...]
```

I have an example in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/RM0iUx?p=preview but it does not render two lines at the same time.

Is this posible to achieve with nvd3-directives? Has anybody done something similar?

I need the two  lines, sets of data values, to be associated with the same key. So when I click on legend corresponding to that  key both lines should be affected

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have two sets with the same name "set", just change the names to be different from  each other and it will be solved.

```
$scope.exampleData = [
    {
      "key": "set1",
      "values":[[0, 0],   [1, 1],  [2, 2],   [3, 3]]
    },
    {
      "key":"set2",
      "values":[[1,0.5],[2,1.5],[2,2.5],[3,2.5]]
    }

    ];
```

Comment: Thanks Seichi for your answer, but indeed i need the two  lines, sets of data values, to be associated with the same key. So when I click on legend corresponding to that  key both lines should be affected

Comment: my bad, I read the docs and i can't find such thing. The only solution i can think about is to put something like `key: "actual"` and `key :"deviation"` on the other but still two different sets.

Comment: yes, I agree. I should implement legend function instead of using it through nvd3-directive. Thanks again!